# DateTime parse issue from one format to another

Tags: c#, datetime, uwp, datetime-format, date-conversion

I have a UWP app that gets installed on PCs which are having various DateTime formats. (Eg: dd/mm/yyyy, dd-mm-yy, etc...). However, the backend API is always accepting the following format. `"MM/dd/yyyy" + " " + "hh:mm:ss tt"`.

I need a way to convert any formatted DateTime variable into a string with the above-mentioned format. How do I achieve it?

I have the following code but do not seems to work.

`dateval` comes from `dateTime.Now`. OS's short date format is dd-mm-yy. So `dateval` is on that format.
I need a way to convert whatever the format is into a string with given format `"MM/dd/yyyy" + " " + "hh:mm:ss tt"`

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-clientTime", dateval.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy" + " " + "hh:mm:ss tt"));
```

Please note that I don't have the exact format to use the TryParse method.

Comment: `DateTime` variables do not have a format. `DateTime.ToString` has an overload that takes an `IFormatProvider` and you can pass the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` so that it doesn't use the current culture information.

Comment: What you need to do is unclear. Do you have a DateTime and you want to convert it to a string? Easy, use the `ToString` overload you reference in your question. Why do you say it doesn't work? Do you have a string in an unknown format and you want to parse it? You're out of luck: it's impossible. Could you explain your problem a little more?

Comment: DateTime ParseExact has an overload that takes an array of formats.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you very much adding the culture solved my issue. A. Chiesa Yes I have a DateTime and needed to convert it to a string. You were right along with HereticMonkey. Thanks again to you both.

Comment: @jdweng I do not have prior info regarding the formats. Thanks for the support.

Comment: See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings